# Chrome://inspect displaying device though not displaying any opened tabs

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging, inspect

I am trying to utilize chrome for remote debugging of an android web application. I am unable to get any open tabs from the device to show under chrome://inspect list for remote debugging.

I have done the following:

1. Made sure my device driver is installed appropriately.
2. Turned on developer mode and usb debugging on my device via the developer menu.
3. Checked and made sure that my device is listed in adb list via issuing "adb devices" from the command line.

My device is displayed under the device list via (chrome://inspect) just cant seem to get any open tabs listed any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Device: 
Samsung Galaxy Tablet 10.1 
Android 4.2.2

[image]

Comment: [Debug xwalkview or webview remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692358/6521116)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok you must use chrome mobile in order to debug any webviews or browser tabs. No other browser works. I was unaware of this.

//Edit

As of Android version 4.4 or later this is no longer the case. Android 4.4 has support for debugging internal Webviews. Please see https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

Answer (score 14):

Using chrome://inspect/#devices, if the device is detected, but tabs open in chrome on the device are not listed, look for the "activate USB debugging" option in the chrome settings-->developer options tab on the device. This is in addition to the USB debugging option you've already checked in the Android developer settings.

Answer (score 4):

After connecting your device, make sure you open Chrome browser on the device and after that refresh the Chrome window on your PC. This will display the entry of the opened Chrome browser on the device. It will not launch if you don't first open Chrome browser on your phone

Answer (score 3):

If none of the above mentioned is applicable for you, or none of them solved the problem for you, you might wanna do:

```
 adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

from your command line.

Comment: An explanation for why this might help would make this answer better. This approach did not help me.

Answer (score -1):

I already tried that. 
It did not work for me, but I found this:

- first open a new folder for a bookmark
- then you need to use this in the URL copy and paste this to your v=bookmark URL:

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0
```

Once you've done that you can name it anything you want.

> (NOTE, you need to be in the tab you will like to inspect/edit).

Just click on the bookmark you just made then you will be able to practically edit anything you want to with this editing mode.

Hopefully That Helped You. (: