# How to debug Crosswalk webview remotely?

Tags: android, android-webview, google-chrome-devtools, crosswalk-runtime

I'm trying to use XWalkView in Android 5.

When I try to inspect an XWalkView in chrome://inspect, I can see the name of the app that is running, but no options for inspection. I also attempted in Canary, but it never got past USB auth for debug.

How can I use chrome dev tools to debug XWalkView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To debug xwalk webview remotely is similar to webview except the webview config.

**a.**  Config your chrome and device for  debugging. Refer to [google articles](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3) or [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13801819/6521116).

**b.**  Config your webivew for debugging. (**difference between webview and xwalkview**) Refer to [xwalkview doc](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html#Debugging).

For xwalkview,  `XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);`

(For webview,    `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); //v4.4+`) Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29696985/6521116).

Answer (score 4):

try using

```
XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
```

To enable remote debugging on my application.